# How can I disable kext signing in Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: macos, code-signing, kernel-extensions

I know the disadvantages of disabling kext signing, but I was wondering how I can actually disable this on Mac OS X 10.10 "Yosemite"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To disable the kext signing security setting:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1
```

After changing this setting you need to restart the computer to have OS X recognize it.

It is important to note that the kext-signing setting is global, if you disable it you should be careful to only install system drivers from sources that you trust.

To reenable again use:

```
sudo nvram -d boot-args
```

Comment: so how do you enable it back ON ?

Comment: Careful: You may already have set other boot-args (I did, to enable old-style external monitor behavior on my Macbook). To check, use the command `nvram boot-args`. If that prints any values (e.g. "iog=0x0"), add them to the above command using a comma, like this: `sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1,iog=0x0`. Then, to disable the kext-dev-mode, do not use the "-d" command but rather omit that part when setting the old boot-args.

Comment: I have a MacPro 4.1 and the "nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1" command doesn't save the value persistent in the NVRAM. When I look with "nvram -p" directly after setting it, it prints out the value. After a reboot, it's gone. How can that happen, or better, how can that be repaired?

Comment: Ok, my question is solved: the Mavericks-to-Yosemite upgrade broke the NVRAM. After a NVRAM-reset the boot-args value keeps stored.

Comment: I've been trying to do this to avoid an issue with my VPN client, but I keep getting `nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) general error` as an error message.  I can't find what "general error" might mean. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Apple's documentation:

> To enable or disable System Integrity Protection, you must boot to
>   Recovery OS and run the csrutil(1) command from the Terminal.
>
> Boot to Recovery OS by restarting your machine and holding down the
>   Command and R keys at startup. Launch Terminal from the Utilities
>   menu. Enter the following command: $ csrutil enable
>
> After enabling or disabling System Integrity Protection on a machine,
>   a reboot is required.

Source: [Configuring System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH5-SW1)

Still quoting:

> As of OS X El Capitan, the kext-dev-mode boot-arg is now obsolete.
>
> `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1" # Has No Effect`

Source: [Kernel Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/KernelExtensions/KernelExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH4-SW1)