# Yosemite problem with Xbox 360 Controller Driver

Tags: macos, system-settings, games, driver

A few months ago, I downloaded this Xbox360ControllerDriver, which I believe it was the .11 Version and was working fine by the time.

Recently, I bought a new wired Xbox 360 controller, thinking that it would be the easiest and fastest to hook up with the iMac. When I first plugged in the controller into the computer, the Xbox360ControlllerDriver recognised it very well. Although, the program I was trying to use the controller with didn't recognised it at all, which led me to download the new version of the Driver, the .14 version.

After downloading and installing the Driver, I've got the following error:

```
 `Preferences Error: Could not load XBox 360 Controllers preference pane`
```

Obviously doing this was not the solution; I downgraded to de previous version of the Driver, the .11 version which did not give positive responses and upgraded back to the .14 version. After several failed attempts, I started a research on how make it work with the Yosemite. Turns our I did the opposite.

Somehow by surfing in the internet, I found what appeared to me the solution to my problem, which include some terminal codes like `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"` and `sudo kextcache -m /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/Startup/Extensions.mkext /System/Library/Extensions`

Without success, after applying all the previous codes and rebooting the computer for several times and also deleting the previous version of the software before installing the new one and more, I come to you wise people hoping for a solution.

[image: This is the System Preferences error I got after installing the .14 version and kept getting no matter what version it is now.]

Comment: kext files (which are basically Mac's version of a device driver) have to be signed to be used in Yosemite. If they are not signed, the system will refuse to load them. [This question/answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163059) covers using unsigned kexts, but note that this will allow ANY kexts to be loaded,